# Is this a conditional statement?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

We were given a passage and were asked to identify any simple or compound mathematical statements from the passage. I came across this sentence,

***"After the time given for each test item runs out, each student must raise his/her board with their answer on it, facing the teacher."***,

and thought it might be a conditional statement concealed in an instruction-form sentence.

I thought it MIGHT be written as *"If the time given for each test item runs out, then each student must raise his/her board with their answer on it, facing the teacher."* But I am not certain about this interpretation. Could this be a conditional statement?

Comment: Works for me: IF it is true that time has run out .... THEN it is true that students must....

Comment: Thank you for your input. Then assuming it is indeed a conditional statement, could the conclusion "Each student must raise his/her board with their answer on it, facing the teacher." be a conjunction? 

It could be written as "Each student must raise his/her board with their answer on it and each student must face the teacher."

Comment: Yes ... and you could even see it as having *three* conjuncts:  1. students must raise board, 2. board must have their answer on it, 3. board must face teacher